# Access attributes of subclassed User in Django

Tags: python, django

This seems really simple and I'm probably missing something, but I'm struggling with the following model structure:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
    
class User(AbstractUser):

    @property
    def is_author(self):
        return False
    
    @property
    def is_editor(self):
        return False

class Author(User):

    @property
    def is_author(self):
        return True

class Editor(Author):

    @property
    def is_editor(self):
        return True
```

Basically I want to have a generic user class and then a subclass called Author and a subclass of that called Editor, each with slightly different properties. This seems to work at the database level, but when I get a User in the context of the app that is also an Author or Editor, I can't get access to the Author or Editor class methods/properties. I tried playing with `__init__` to no real effect; have I structured this wrong? How do I call `is_author` on an Author that's also a User and get `True` back?

Edit: I may have found a way around this keeping the current User structure in place but handling the processing of whether the User is an Author/Editor in the view stage, with something like:

```
try:
    Author.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    is_author = True
except Author.DoesNotExist:
    is_author = False
```

Then passing `is_author` into the template context, where it can be interpreted.

Comment: User model is determined by [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) in settings.py, which can be exactly one class only.  You can probably monkeypatch it to make it work as a factory, but I think it would be better to use the same class for both Author/Editor and determine which one is it by a custom column added for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's sort of annoying, in that I want custom attributes on different types of users, and there's some risk (I suppose) that a user that's not supposed to have those attributes would have them filled out.